# VBA Refer to TextBox or Label using a loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to replace the following:

```
txt1.Text = ""
txt2.Text = ""
txt3.Text = ""
txt4.text = ""
...continues for quite awhile
```

With:

```
Dim cCont As Control

For Each cCont In Me.Controls

If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" Then
'reset textbox value
   ???
End If
Next cCont
```

How do I refer to the textbox using the generic 'Control'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already have your control in cCont.

```
Dim cCont As Control

For Each cCont In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf cCont Is MSForms.TextBox Then
    cCont.Text = "hi"
    MsgBox cCont.Name
  End If
Next
```

If you're confused by the fact you don't get the `Text` property from IntelliSense, just cast the `Control` to a more derived type:

```
Dim cCont As Control

For Each cCont In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf cCont Is MSForms.TextBox Then
    Dim cText As MSForms.TextBox

    Set cText = cCont

    cText.Text = "hi"
    MsgBox cText.Name
  End If
Next
```

This will use early binding instead of late binding, and you'll get your code suggestions.

Comment: It is good practice to declare all local variables immediately after you sub or function header.  "Variables declared within a block inside a procedure (such as a For loop) are initialized on entry to the procedure. These initializations take effect whether or not your code ever executes the block."  [source link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35styb3a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx "source link")

Comment: @ray023 Your comment is highly irrelevant. It concerns VB.NET, which is different to VBA, and it does not affect the way `cText` is used. Nobody cares if `cText` is automatically set to `Nothing` when you enter the procedure. The point is, it won't be set to `cCont` until you get into the loop.

Comment: I'm somebody and I care, dang-it!! :D  The link may have been VB.NET, but the variable lifetime as mentioned from the link also applies to VBA.  The point is cText lives in the procedure, not in the FOR EACH LOOP.  So wouldn't you rather just group all the variables together in a nice, tight package?  I *know* it's nitpicking and I still gave +1 FWIW.

Comment: @ray023 You seem to be confusing lifetime with scope :) Life time = entire procedure, scope = ? In VBA, it's "from the point of declaration to the end of the procedure." In VB.NET, it's "from the point of declaration to the end of enclosing block." The fact that a variable *lives* at a certain moment doesn't mean you can *use* it. You can only use it where lifetime and scope overlap. This is why I often find it useful to declare variables where they are used.

Comment: @GSerge Hmmm....enlightening; and pbly not the first nor the last time I get terminology mixed :P  So, just to belabor a point that has *nothing* to do with the orig ques, let's say this code is not at the top of the proc.  In fact, there are 100 lines of code between the proc header and this loop.  I can see why you would declare cCont above the loop, but why not cText as well?  The only reason I ask is because once cText comes in *scope*, it's going to stay that way.  Seeing the code the way it is gives someone the impression that cText goes back out of scope; which is not the way VBA works.

Comment: I thought it could be declared ``cCont as MSForms.TextBox``, so it wouldn't be necessary to use ``TypeOf``. But as I was testing, I've got a ``Type Mismatch`` pointing to the ``Next`` command. Anyone could explain what is going on here?

Comment: @ray023 Yes, it does stay there. But I'm declaring it inside the loop to say, "I promise to not access this variable outside this loop, despite I technically could." I feel this as a better approach. Giving the next person a better feel of what exactly is going to happen here. (That next person is often me, half a year later.) I would put `cCont` inside the loop, too, but I can't as it's the loop counter and in VBA it cannot be declared within the loop declaration.

Comment: @Oneide All controls on the form get enumerated, not only textboxes. When a non-textbox is going to be fetched, it fails to assign to a `TextBox` variable. But all controls can be assigned to a `Control` variable, which is the base class for them.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks! I think I've got it ... that is why there are a explicit reference for ``Variant``s in the help topic about ``For Each``.