# EXCEL VBA Type mismatch with "Next" highlighted

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

I'm creating small project in **Excel**, and because I'm a VBA newbie I do encounter a lot of problems that I'm trying to resolve on my own. However i can't cope with this:

I created Sub that accepts two objects: `FormName` and `ControlName`.

What i want it to do, is to loop through every Control in specific `UserForm` and populate every `ListBox` it encounters, from another `ListBox`.

I created this funny string comparison, because I need to operate on objects in order to execute the line with `AddItem`. This comparison actually works well, no matter how ridiculous it is. However when I launch the program, I got

> Type Mismatch error

and to my surprise "Next" is being highlighted. I have no idea how to fix this, nor what is wrong.

```
Public Sub deploy(ByRef FormName As Object, ByRef ControlName As Object)
Dim i As Integer
Dim O As msforms.ListBox

i = 0
For Each O In FormName.Controls
If Left(FormName.Name & O.Name, 16) = Left(FormName.Name & ControlName.Name, 16) Then
O.AddItem (FormName.Podgląd.List(i))
i = i + 1
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I call this sub using:

```
Call deploy(UserForm1, UserForm1.ListBox3)
```

Above, I use `Listbox3` because otherwise i got error saying that **variable is not defined**. However in my comparison I kinda override this.

If someone can explain in simple words, how to fix this type mismatch issue or how to write it in more elegant way

Comment: Not all elements in `FormName.Controls` are `msforms.ListBox`es.

Comment: Change the type to ```Dim O As Control```

Comment: Oh that is true, I did't know that would cause problems. Is there any way to loop only through ListBoxes in specific UserForm then?

Comment: @Warcupine thank you, now i do not have error, but the listboxes are not being populated. I'll check things.

Comment: I think you need to name them consistently and check their names to determine the type but I don't work with forms too often, there may be a better way to go about it.

Comment: @Warcupine https://stackoverflow.com/a/6060219/11683

Comment: You also do not need the extra set of parenthesis here: `O.AddItem FormName.Podgląd.List(i)`

Comment: @gserg Ahh, that is a much better way. Honestly that makes a pretty good dupe target for this question.

Comment: Many thanks to you all, now I'm sure I'll manage to make it work <3 Happy New Year guys!