# Loop through one or multiple selected Chart Objects

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a code that works whether if I select one or multiple charts in Excel.

Actually I use this code, but it fail when only one chart is seleted :

```
Dim obj As Object

'Check if any charts have been selected
If Not ActiveChart Is Nothing Then

    MsgBox ("Select multiple charts")

Else
    For Each obj In Selection

    'If more than one chart selected
    If TypeName(obj) = "ChartObject" Then

        Call AnotherMacro(obj.Chart)

    End If
Next

End If
```

I'm looking for a solution working into a unique Sub.

Thanks for your help

Comment: So before trying the `For Each`, test if `Selection` is already a `ChartArea`?

Comment: I would be very wary of using `Selection` with Charts. It's too easy to accidentally select an element of a chart, instead of the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub iterateSelectedCharts()
    Dim obj As Object
    If TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Then 'for the case of only one selected chart:
        'Call AnotherMacro(ActiveChart)
    ElseIf TypeName(Selection) = "DrawingObjects" Then
        For Each obj In Selection
            If TypeName(obj) = "ChartObject" Then
                'Call AnotherMacro(obj.Chart)
            End If
        Next obj
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please, select charts") 'for the case when selection contains
                                         'other type of object(s): cells, rectangles, circles etc.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it.

Comment: @CLR Not really... I adapted the code. I missed the case of selecting a single object not being a chart. Now, it covers this aspect, too (I think...). :)

Comment: Why do people insist on the fuzzy `TypeName(o) = "obj"` instead of [the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6060219/11683) strict `TypeOf o Is obj`?..

Comment: @GSerg I do not know why `people` proceed in that way, but i do that because, **in cases you cannot be sure about the returned variable type** you can simple check it using `Debug.print TypeName(Selection)`, or `TypeName(obj)`. Otherwise, it is possible to use `TypeOf`, but in order to get the type you should use `Debug.Print TypeOf Selection is DrawingObjects`, followed by `Debug.Print  TypeOf Selection is ChartArea`, **if you have clear expectations related to all possible involved variables type**. In the first case the type is simple returned even if you do not know anything about it.

Comment: @GSerg I use `TypeOf only in case of iteration between controls on a form, using something as `If TypeOf control is MsForms.ComboBox Then` do something...

Comment: @FaneDuru But here you are using an `If` rather than a `Debug.Print`, and in that `If` you are expecting such pre-known types as `ChartArea` or `DrawingObjects`. And you make the `If`s to be `If TypeOf Selection Is ChartArea`, it does not prevent you from `Debug.Print TypeName(Selection)` at the same time.

Comment: @GSerg What I wanted to suggest was the next scenario: Not being sure what object type should be used, using `Debug.print TypeName(Selection)` is the easiest way to determine it. Then the faster way to continue is to place the returned string in clipboard, replace `Debug.Print` with `If`, place `=' after it and paste the copied string followed by `Then`. At least, this is the way I proceed. Without trying to say that everybody should proceed in that way...

Comment: I try to avoid the repetition of the Call AnotherMacro(obj.Chart) part , any clue ?

Comment: @Adri Please, elaborate... If your code would return a **single chartObject** after `Else If`, you can set a `Chart` variable to be set and call the function using it, once, at the end of the code. But, if you need to call the function during iteration, this involving the possibility to call it more then once, what do you have in mind when say "to avoid repetition"? I can adapt the code to place all necessary objects in an array, or in a collection, call the function according to it, but **a new iteration will be required**...

Comment: @Adri If you adapt the called function to accept (instead of a `Chart` object) a collection, i can adapt the code, but anyhow the iteration must be done inside the called `Sub`. Do you have in mind something different? Excuse may lack of modesty,  but I think I can do whatever you need, if you better explain what you really want, from this point of view. Since you need to **do something** more than once, during the iteration, you cannot avoid calling the `Sub` many times, except the case you better like collecting the objects to be processed and move iteration inside the respective `Sub`...

Comment: I'd like to elaborate it but my I'm limited, so I ask for your help :). I'm looking for a code that don't repeat the "call AnotherMacro" part so that it could be avoid to write a new macro and the process of the graph can be write once in the current Sub. 
I understand that there is maybe a way to store the one graph object into an array and then pass the array to the loop, if multiple graph the array is the selection. So that the loop would be executed for 1 or multiple charts. What do you think ?

Comment: @Adri 1. Don't you think that my above code answer your question as it was formulated? 2. I still cannot understand **why** to avoid more calls, since they are needed. If you just hate many such calls I can adapt the above code to place all charts needed to be processed in a collection and pass it to the called `Sub`. But are you able to adapt the `Sub` in discussion to process such a collection? I can do it for an array, too but it is the same question mark. In fact you only **move** the iteration in another place, consuming Excel resources without any efficiency...

Comment: @Adri But if you only want playing with this issue I can design such a code to deliver what you want... I mean a collection/array of suitable charts. But are you able to process it?

Comment: That would great ! Inside the loop I think I can manage it

Comment: @Adri But you did not answer my above questions, especially the one marked as `1.`... **Does the above code answer your question as it is**?

Comment: In the present code it repeat twice the call to AnotherMacro. 
1. I want to avoid to maintain one macro for the loop and another to manage the case of one or multiple graph. It multiples by 2 the number of macro at the end. 
2. The goal is to write my code directly in the loop. For maintening reason I want to avoid to repeat the code at two locations in the macro.
I hope its clear for you, thanks for your time.

Comment: @Adri Where **in your question is written what you say now**? Did I miss this part? Please, copy it and **paste in a following comment**. We here are not mind readers. a). It does not repeat twice. It repeats only after `ElseIf`, according to the number of charts inside selection. It **does not multiply anything**! b). Write the code in the loop, as you want! Nothing is clear, I cannot get you. I wish you a nice day!

Comment: I'm deeply sorry if I was unclear in my demand and I don't want to waste your time or the time of other People trying to help me. Again, I apologize. In my initial demand in my code exemple I call AnotherMacro only once but my code doesn't work when I call it with one graph, thats the point. The fact that there is only one call to AnotherMacro is important and I agree that I was not clear in my demand. Now, If you understand that can you make another proposition ? I would be thank full.

Comment: @Adri I am afraid that this comment only proves that you did not understand anything from the code you are talking about, no offence... Your code calls that `AnotherMacro` **as many times as number of charts in the objects selection**. Then, only the code you are talking about **calls the Sub only once, if only a chart is selected**. What should I propose in such circumstances? Which is the problem for you? The fact that the code line `Call AnotherMacro(obj.Chart)` appears twice? Do you understand that **each sequence in a `If` statement is executed only once, the other part is skipped**?

Comment: I'm aware that AnotherMacro  will be called as many time as of the number of selected graph. I know what is a loop. I don't want to repeat AnotherMacro for writing and maintening code reason. Because if I dont want to call AnotherMacro and write long code instead I will have repeat the long code, and I dont want that. Hope its clear explicated this way ;). I want to do that for writting code efficency, not execution time, the macro will be light and fast to execute at the end.

Comment: @Adri I am afraid that we have different opinions about code efficiency. But I can live with that. I wish you succes in doing it in your way!

Comment: We all have different exeperience, and I would be glad that you it share on this forum. Looking foreward to read from you.

Comment: @Adri I tried doin that, I tried suggesting that a question should be answered **as it has been formulated**, I tried justifying that **it is not possible to deal other way with only one selected chart**, but all was for nothing... To place the objects in a collection/array, **only because you want that**, not obeying the community rules, is not my way of  acting here, even if it would not be too complicate. Sometimes, the way you are asking for may determine us to jump over the rules, but was not your case. At least, on my taste...